# IPTCInfo change keywords without quotation marks

Tags: metadata, iptc, iptcinfo

I try to change the keywords for some pics, with a csv file that has the nessescary data.

The problem is that I can't change the keywords without getting quotation marks into the array element(see: **"b'Fallow_deer'"**) .

I hope someone can help.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d80gG.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
string1 = 'Fallow_deer'
string1 = string1.encode('UTF-8')
array = [string1]
print(array)
```

[What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)